# Convert string to boost::gregorian::greg_month

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

In the Boost date time library, is there a utility function for converting month short strings (e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr) to boost::gregorian::greg_month type? The documentation for the library isn't great and I can't see anything in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky work around could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

int main(void)
{
  auto ptr = boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr();

  if (ptr)
  {
    auto it = ptr->begin();
    for(; it != ptr->end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

This map contains mapping between all the short/long names and the short necessary to create a `greg_month` instance. Just need to create a little wrapper around it...

per Graeme's discovery, there is a convenience function which wraps this already [`boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/doxy.html#gregorian_reference)

Comment: Just found a function already wrappin this up:  boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<month_type>. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Graeme, aha - it had to be there somewhere - it's a pretty trivial function... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are boost date time facets that can be used to create locales and put into streams.

Beware though that if you are going to print or parse a large number of dates and times you do not create the facet and locale for each one you parse.

Look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_input_facet) for documentation on inputting dates. Some of their examples use short month names, which appears to have `%b` as its [format specifier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#format_strings)